# need to explain bash grep regular expression grep -E '(^|[^0-9.])'2 *.c

Tags: bash, grep

I'm  confused with this grep command. I would like somebody to explain it for me.

For each digit i, search for the (nondigit)i sequence in the textd.sh)

```
grep -E '(^|[^0-9.])'i *.c

for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do
   grep -E '(^|[^0-9.])'$i *.c > lines_with_${i}
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `grep` command:

```
grep -E '(^|[^0-9.])'$i *.c
```

Is matching digits 0, 1, 2, 3,.... in a loop.

While matching these digits it makes sure that digits are either at start (`^`) OR else there is a non-digit non-dot character before these digits (`[^0-9.]`).

So for example it will match:

```
abc 1
2
def5
```

and it won't match:

```
abc.1
```